# How to I tell parent state controller something happened in child state controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In the context of the setup below, how would one tell the parent controller (`ZoneController`) something happened in the child controller (`ZoneCodeController`)?

```
.state('zone',
{
    url:'/zone',
    controller:'ZoneController',
    templateUrl:'views/zone.html'
})
.state('zone.code',
{
    url:'/:zoneCode',
    controller:'ZoneCodeController',
    templateUrl:function(stateParams)
    {
        return 'views/zone-codes/'+stateParams.zoneCode+'.html';
    }
}
```

Comment: define `something happened`. Can share data through a service, or use custom events that can also pass data throughout app.

Comment: What I need is to only refresh the table, nothing else. So I would like the parent controller to know that the location hash changed and have it get data for that location hash.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to create a service for sharing data across controllers.  I've created something like:

```
angular.module('MODULENAME', []).factory('SharedHashTable', function($rootScope, $log)  {
    var data = {};

    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
            data.key = value;
        },
        get: function(key) {
            return data.key;
        }

    };
});
```

Then you can add SharedHashTable to whatever controller can call its set or get methods:

```
// in controller 1
SharedHashTable.set("MyData", $scope.myData);
// in controller 2
$scope.otherData = SharedHashTable.get("MyData");
```

Comment: but will the SharedHashTable.get("MyData"); in controller 2 always run when SharedHashTable.set("MyData", $scope.myData); in controller 1 is executed?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to subscribe the parent controller to an event that happens within the child you can use $emit.

```
.controller('ZoneController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('eventName', function (data) {
        // Do something.
    });
})

.controller('ZoneCodeController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.somethingHappened = function () {
        var data = {key: 'value'};

        // Publish the event up the controller hierarchy.
        $scope.$emit('eventName', data);
    }

});
```

Alternatiely if you're just looking to share data a service is likely to be the better choice.